# Angular 2 pass variable to component dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that is initialized with an empty property `editingProduct` which is the product that is to be edited, but is empty until the user has selected a product.

The editing component is nested inside the parent component (a list of products) like this

```html
<p-dialog header="Product" 
          [(visible)]="displayCreateDialog" 
          [responsive]="true" 
          showEffect="fade" 
          [modal]="true">
    <qs-product-create *ngIf="displayCreateDialog" 
                       [product]="editingProduct" 
                       (save)="onSaved($event)">
    </qs-product-create>
</p-dialog>
```

The only reason this works if because of the `ngIf` binding, but it feels like a hack. Is there no way to sort of initialize the `qs-product-create`s `product` input from the component logic in the parent component? Or maybe set up the binding in a way that it gets updated when the `editingProduct` changes.

Comment: if you remove`*ngIf="displayCreateDialog"` what would happen?

Comment: Then the `editingProduct` is empty when the component is initialized and the selected product is never passed to the editing component.

Comment: it sounds a litter odd to me. on selected/clicked event of product, you can assign value to editingProduct. right?

Comment: Yes, when 'edit' is clicked the `editingProduct` is updated, but the new value is not passed to `qs-product-create`.

Comment: Its not possible. have you checked with `qs-product-create component's ngOnChanges hook`?

Comment: Another thing to check is if you get an exception when you pass in the initial `undefined` value.  If you immediately try to de-reference it (use the dot operator) without checking for undefined you would get an exception which would then cause the child element to stop working (so the updated value could get set but the component wouldn't respond).  The *ngIf would mean the component doesn't get created so the error wouldn't happen, which is actually a legitimate thing to do.  You could check for null in the component and use `product?.whatever` in template code to also fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest inside parent templates, just pass `product` from `p-dialog` to `qs-product-create` again. I tested the following code and it is working

**app.com.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-com',
    template: `
        <h2><a [href]="titleUrl">{{title}}</a></h2>
        <input [(ngModel)]="product">
        <p-dialog [product]="product"></p-dialog>
`
})
export class ParentCom {

    title = "stackoverflow.com/q/39471050";
    titleUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/39471050";

    product;

    constructor() { }

}
```

**p-dialog.com.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'p-dialog',
    template: `
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <qs-product-create [product]="product"></qs-product-create>
`
})
export class PDialogCom {

    title = "P Dialog";

    @Input() product;

    constructor() { }

}
```

**qs-product-create.com.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'qs-product-create',
    template: `
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <div>{{product}}</div>
`
})
export class QsProductCreateCom {

    title = "QA Product Create";

    @Input() product;

    constructor() { }

}
```